# How can I find out whether I can use the ATMs in a specific country?

Tags: money, exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which credit cards have global coverage?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/722/which-credit-cards-have-global-coverage)

When it comes to electronic bank machines, there are pretty much four categories of countries:

1. Countries where the majority of ATMs accept common foreign cards.
2. Countries where there are ATMs but foreign cards do not work (e.g. Iran).
3. Countries with ATMs that accept foreign cards but should not be used
   due to very bad exchange rates (e.g. Venezuela).
4. Countries that do not have ATMs at all (Myanmar until Nov.2011)

Do I have to google this for every country I am going to? Or is there a nice list somewhere with all the countries in the last three categories?