# What is the best source of information for ATM availability?

Tags: online-resources, atms

From Wikitravel:

> Some developing countries either have no ATMs, very limited ATMs, or
>   are not connected to the international networks. This includes Myanmar
>   in Southeast Asia, as well as parts of Africa. In Japan, most bank
>   ATMs don't work with international cards (the cards are even an
>   incompatible size), so you need to look for a post office, 7/11 or
>   Citibank ATM. In certain countries, not every ATM accepts foreign
>   credit or debit cards. So check in-advance about what's available, and
>   do what's necessary to ensure you have adequate cash during your
>   travels.

What is the best source of information for finding out about ATM availability? I am travelling around Europe (including Eastern Europe) and trying to figure out what card/card(s) to obtain to make sure that I am never caught without money.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which credit cards have global coverage?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/722/which-credit-cards-have-global-coverage)

Comment: @Doc: These questions are completely different. 1. Credit cards!=ATMs. There are debit cards as well and credit cards can be used at stores, not just ATMs. 2. That question asks about general availability, while I'm asking about how to find out about specific availability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you go outside of your home country the vast majority of ATM transactions are handled via either the Visa or MasterCard owned networks.  Even where they are handled via other mechanisms, you can pretty much presume that any ATM which is going to to allow international cards to be used is going to be a part of the Visa and/or MasterCard networks.  This is true regardless of whether the card is a Credit Card, a Visa/MasterCard logoed Debit Card, or just a plain bank ATM card with the Plus, Maestro or Cirrus logos on the back.

Both Visa (Plus) and MasterCard (Maestro/Cirrus) have features on their websites where you can search a specific city anywhere in the world to find ATMs that will work with any Visa/MasterCard cards.

Presuming your ATM card is marked with either a MasterCard, Maestro or Cirrus logo then it should work at any of the ATMs listed on the [Mastercard locator](http://www.mastercard.com/global/atmlocations/). Mastercard also have a [Mobile App](http://www.mastercard.us/mobile.html) for iPhone, Android, and Blackberry.

If it's marked with either a Visa, Electron or Plus logos, then it should work at any ATM on the [Visa locator](http://visa.via.infonow.net/locator/global/), or on the [mobile version](http://visa.via.infonow.net/mobile/).

Comment: Hmm not so simple. In Australia, Plus does not exist. My Visa cards have supported Cirrus for many years. This is probably why when I'm overseas it seems to *never* work to try to use my Visa card in an ATM marked with Maestro but not with Cirrus. Also when you can use a card with two networks, say Visa or Cirrus, the cost of using one or the other can vary by a huge amount. I avoid using my Visa card in ATMs unless it's an emergency for this very reason.

Comment: I just checked the MasterCard locator for Dar es Salaam and it's wildly inaccurate. :(

Comment: The Visa locator link isn't working.

Answer (score 7):

You'd probably want to know about the Global ATM Alliance.  The Global ATM Alliance is a joint venture of several major international banks that allows customers of their banks to use their ATM card or debit card at another bank within the Global ATM Alliance with no International ATM Access fees. However, other fees, such as an international transaction or foreign currency fee, may still apply for some account holders. Participating banks cover Australasia, Asia, Europe, Africa, North America and South America.

For amazing detail of bank availability and ATM usage around the world check the Wikipedia page on the [Global ATM Alliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_ATM_Alliance).

**EDIT**

Also found the following two ATM locator sites:

- [Mastercard /  Maestro / Cirrus ATM locator](http://www.mastercard.us/cardholder-services/atm-locator.html)
- [Visa ATM locator](http://visa.via.infonow.net/locator/global/jsp/SearchPage.jsp)

This would have especially been useful in places like Nukus, Uzbekistan, where there was just ONE of the one type...hidden away in a bank on the non-tourist side of town...

Comment: That only includes one Australian bank. Maybe I should open an account with them as a backup

Comment: The "Global ATM Alliance" is little more than marketing. The only benefit is that they do not charge the few dollar fee that you might have paid otherwise.  In most countries there are numerous cards that will give the same benefit with any ATM worldwide. eg, for Australia there's NAB Gold banking, Citibank, 28 Degrees (a credit card, but if you keep it in credit there no ATM or currency conversation fees) and several others.

Comment: For some of us, avoiding a "few dollar fee" on every withdrawal is a big deal. No big deal on a a two week trip with an income. A big deal indeed on a year+ trip with no income, especially in countries where the cost of living is very low.