# How can I get a list of which companies accept Mastercard for cash advances?

Tags: europe, online-resources, money, dubai, payment-cards

From [statson.org](http://stason.org/TULARC/finance/consumer-credit/103-Is-MasterCard-better-than-Visa-or-vice-versa-What-abo.html:):

> Again, in France, almost any bank or cash machine (if you have a
>   4-digit PIN) can give you a cash advance on Visa (Carte Bleue), but
>   only a few banks (Credit Agricole, Credit Mutuel, and all Post
>   Offices) and cash machines can give you a M-C cash advance.

I've searched Google and Mastercard's website, but I can't find a list of which banks accept Mastercard for cash advances. I'll be travelling in Europe (20 countries) and Duabi. How can I find out which banks or ATM operators will accept Mastercard in a particular country?

**Update**

Apparently, [Cirrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirrus_%28interbank_network%29) is the interbank network used by Mastercard.

**Related questions:**

- [ATM availability](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6053/what-is-the-best-source-of-information-for-atm-availability) - I'm looking for a list of companies, rather than the locations for specific ATMs

Comment: I don't think you want a bank, but instead a cash machine - I don't think a teller will let you withdraw cash on a credit card, but the ATMs should. Is that what you mean? If so, I suspect the question should instead be "which ATM operators accept mastercard", since there are ATMs not run by banks

Comment: @Gagravarr: I haven't done it, but it is my understanding that any bank participating in the credit card network (e.g. Visa or MasterCard) will give you a cash advance at the teller window.  Their contract with the network requires them to do so.

Comment: Changed to bank or ATM operator

Comment: @Casebash Can you clarify what your question is here? Any bank or ATM that displays the MasterCard logo will allow you to withdraw cash - so if one doesn't, find another! Either an ATM support MasterCard, or it doesn't, and by experience practically all ATMs I've seen in Europe accept both.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: That's what I thought it would be like, but according to statson.org this isn't necessarily the case. If I have a list of banks, then I can ask someone what ATMs are nearby and I'll know which ones can let me take cash out

Comment: @Casebash I think what the statement here means is that only the two banks + post office support the MasterCard network. So you have your answer already - find an ATM by one of those banks, and withdraw cash. It *doesn't* mean that only 'some' ATMs from those banks will give you cash. Separately, the term 'cash advance' itself means something specific - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cash_advance. Do you just want to withdraw cash, or are you specifically looking for 'cash advance' in its meaning of 'emergency cash under certain circumstances'?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: Well, "cash advance" is kind of a misnomer in my case as I will prepay it in advance. That website is referring to France. I am going to be visiting many other countries, which may have other banks that can do cash advances

Comment: @Casebash Well...then it's not a cash advance. If you're talking about a prepaid MasterCard then it works the same as withdrawing using a credit/debit card.

Answer (score 5):

Having visited France more times than I could be bothered counting over the past few years, I've yet to find an ATM that didn't accept my MasterCard Credit Card.  They may exist, but the majority of ATMs certainly do allow cash advances (whether it's a true cash advance or a withdrawal against a credit balance).  You can search for Mastercard supported ATMs [on their website](http://www.mastercard.com/global/atmlocations/), or using their [ATM Hunter](http://www.mastercard.us/mobile.html) mobile app (iPhone or Android).

In-branch cash advances are a different matter altogether. Banks are NOT under any obligation to give a cash advance against a credit card issued by another bank, and although many will do it, they will generally charge you a non-trivial fee for the privileged (far more than the fee to use the ATM will be, if there is one).  The only situation I can think of where this would be a viable solution would be if the magnetic strip on your card was to fail. (Hint: always make sure you've got at least 2 cards!)

Answer (score 1):

A list of businesses that accept Mastercard will actually be the client list of Mascercard  Corp., so there is little chance they make that document available to the public otherwise the first thing VISA or AE would do is to call every single name on that list to onboard them.

Comment: MasterCard's business model is that almost all of their business is done through banks and third party clearing companies - very few of their merchants are actually "clients" of MasterCard and thus their client list is actually relatively small. M/C just act as the middle-man between the bank that issued the card and the bank that the merchant is using. (Yes, that's massively oversimplified, but...)